# Regression over time specific year as weight

Tags: r, regression

I am doing a regression with panel data of EU countries over time with observations from 2007-16. I want to use the observation for 2007 for each specific country as the weight. Is there a simple way to do this?

The is essentially the regression I run, but I don't think the weighting is working as I intend it to.

```
lm(log(POP25) ~ log(EMPLOY25), weights = POP25, data = data)



structure(list(...1 = 1:6, TIME = 2007:2012, NUTS_ID = c("AT", 
"AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT"), NUMBER = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), POP15 = c(5529.1, 5549.3, 5558.5, 5572.1, 5601.1, 5620.8
), POP20 = c(5047.1, 5063.2, 5072.6, 5090, 5127.1, 5151.9), POP25 = c(4544, 
4560.7, 4571.3, 4587.8, 4621.5, 4639), EMPLOY15 = c(3863.6, 3928.7, 
3909.3, 3943.9, 3982.3, 4013.4), EMPLOY20 = c(3676.2, 3737, 3723.8, 
3761.9, 3802.3, 3835), EMPLOY25 = c(3333.5, 3390.4, 3384.7, 3424.6, 
3454.4, 3486.4)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add some example data e.g. using `dput(head(data))`

Answer (score 1):

You are right - this is not doing what you expect it to. The reason is that you are supplying `POP25` as the weight but you haven't yet made it explicit that you only want the `POP25` value from 2007.

A weights vector needs to be the same length as the dependent and independent variables. The easiest way to do this is by creating a `weights` column in the table, where the value is the `POP25` value for each `NUTS_ID` in the year `2007`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data  <- data  |>
    group_by(NUTS_ID)  |>
    mutate(weights = POP25[TIME==2007])
```

You can then supply this as the weights vector:

```r
lm(log(POP25) ~ log(EMPLOY25), weights = weights, data = data)
```